Top Displays across two joined monitors - 24.04
I'm running v24.04 with dual monitors (Ancor Communications 24" & LG Electronics 22").  The monitors are joined in settings and I scroll across them without issue.  The problem is that the top bar is spread across both resulting in things that are centered being broken between the monitors.
Also, it appears that the system thinks the total monitor is larger than it really is.  If I scroll all the way to the right, the right side of the top bar is now on the left monitor.  It seems that Ubuntu thinks my left display is really twice as wide.
My installation is pretty vanilla and I'm running Wayland.
Any ideas?
Thanks,
--Don

Not enough info. What GPU and what drivers are you using?
